# How to render alphabetically pagination from Material UI Pagination?

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm trying to render the list of words using MUI pagination but in alphabetical order.

> what we have
>
> 1,2,3,...,26

[image: MUI Pagination component]

> what we need
> A,B,C,...,Z

```
wordsList: {
A: [],
B: [],
...,
Z: []
}
```

Comment: Could you share a bit more code? What are you passing to `<Pagination>`?

Comment: Maybe there is no way to do that. You have to write your own pagination component or use other library/framework/package

Comment: Have you tried `renderItem={(item) => <p>{alphabetKeys[item.page]}</p>}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
renderItem={(item) => (
  <PaginationItem {...item} page={alphabet[item.page - 1]} />
)}
```

```js
const { Pagination, PaginationItem } = MaterialUI;

const alphabet = Array.from("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

function BasicPagination() {
  return (
    <Pagination
      count={alphabet.length}
      variant="outlined"
      renderItem={(item) => (
        <PaginationItem {...item} page={alphabet[item.page - 1]} />
      )}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<BasicPagination />);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```